# AppDelegate redirect delegate not triggered anymore in iOS 13.2 (when opening app from Safari)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have a URL Scheme in my info.plist that allows me to have a website redirect to my iOS app. In AppDelegate you can catch this with a delegate method:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("redirected")
    return true
}
```

This all worked fine, but now in iOS 13.2 it just won't trigger anymore... The app does open though, but the delegate doesn't get called. I need this to extract an access token from the URL.

I even created a brand new Xcode project and did everything I am supposed to do according to Apple's docs but it just won't work. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Unless your app completely opts out of using scenes, you need to implement the `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` delegate method from `UISceneDelegate`. This has been true since iOS 13.0.

Comment: Thank you, I tried finding an answer for a long time and never found a mention of scenes... Deleting the scene stuff from info.plist and AppDelegate does make it work the old way. I already added @available tags before to make it work for older iOS. Other option is to use the new scene delegate as you mentioned.